# Does androidx contain replacements for Wear OS classes like WatchFaceService?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to develop a Wear OS watchface using Android Studio.  When I create a new watchface project, the default code uses classes like android.support.wearable.watchface.WatchFaceService and android.support.wearable.watchface.WatchFaceService.Engine.  When I check the [reference documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/watchface/WatchFaceService) for those classes, it says they have been deprecated and superseded by the new androidx.* classes.  However, I have been unable to find any signs of WatchFaceService or related classes in the [androidx documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/packages).

So, what is the current recommended practice for developing Wear OS watchfaces?  Are there replacements for the watchface classes in androidx somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's an error in the documentation; `WatchFaceService` isn't marked as deprecated internally.

At any rate, there are no AndroidX replacements for any of the `android.support.wearable.*` classes. If you want to develop for Wear OS, these are still the classes you need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2021 there is now androidx.wear.watchface

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/watchface/package-summary

with a sample here https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/WatchFaceKotlin